# AHK: trigger replacement within a word

Tags: autohotkey

I use fake email addresses a lot when filling out test forms, and I've got an AHK snippet that spits out the `@mailinator.com` part of an email address for me when I hit ``m`:

``` :*:``m::@mailinator.com ```

The problem is that I have to hit space between the username part of the email address and my backtick key combination, or else AHK doesn't recognize that I'm trying to trigger a replacement.  I want to be able to type `joeuser[backtick]m` instead of `joeuser[space][backtick]m` and get `joeuser@mailinator.com`.

I know this is a minor, silly trivial thing (and I've got a temporary workaround that uses a `{Backspace}` to remove the space), but the workflow makes much more sense to me without the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the ? option:

> ? (question mark): The hotstring will be triggered even when it is inside another word; that is, when the character typed immediately before it is alphanumeric. For example, if *:?:al::airline* is a hotstring, typing "practical " would produce "practicairline ". Use **?0** to turn this option back off.

So, like this:

```
:*?:``m::@mailinator.com
```

[Source](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options)

Comment: The AHK documentation is rather dense, so thanks for pointing that out to me.  Works perfectly!